# Moving a question from GIS to SO

Tags: support, migration

I created a question about `GDAL` and its `C#`-bindings [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60154/support-for-arc-info-binary-grid-format-by-c-bindings-of-gdal) on GIS. So far I received no reply. I saw similar questions answered on SO, so I would like to move it there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag the question for moderation attention and ask for it to be migrated to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask a moderator to do it (by flagging it). Although I never tried it i'm sure they can do it.

You have no upvotes, no comments, no answers. I would simply copy it's content, paste it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and then delete it on GIS.

Comment: Deleting stuff brings bad karma. Migration is the way to go, especially since (when mods are involved) you get an extra layer of verification that the question is indeed a good candidate for the target site.

Comment: @Mat Which is why it's the first option. But i'm curious. What's wrong about deleting 1 question ? Especially if you have no down votes on it.

Comment: It's still a deleted question. Potentially comes into account into the Q-ban heuristics. And potentially wastes someone's time - imagine someone on GIS is typing an answer on GIS right now. If the question gets migrated either their answer will get migrated with it, or at least they'll still have a link to the SO question when they refresh (and can hopefully retrieve their text from their browser cache). If the post is deleted, lost effort + frustration. Far fetched: not really. That's happened to me twice already.

Comment: You're right. Didn't see it this way. Thanks :)